# Docker errors when trying to publish ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have an ASP.NET project (NET6) and I removed Docker support by:

1. Deleting the 'targets' file
2. Deleting the 'docker' file
3. Removing 'Docker' settings from the 'launchsettings.json' file

When I try to publish the project I get the following errors:

> Visual Studio container tools require Docker Desktop.  To get it, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847268

> The "KillAppInsideContainer" task failed unexpectedly.

I've installed Docker Desktop for Windows and I still get these errors when publishing:

> The "KillAppInsideContainer" task failed unexpectedly.

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Shared.Functions.AzureFunctionsFeedDataProvider..ctor(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Services.Logging.ILoggingService)'.

Am I missing other settings / places where Docker is still referenced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a reference to this Nuget package:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets

Once removed, publishing works fine.

Comment: But what if you don't want to remove docker support?